# HIVE:insert overwrite Parquet table error

Tags: hive, parquet

I just do a simple query like this ,but somme Exception appear.

```html
insert overwrite table stage_dfqp.user_currency partition (dt='2018-05-16')
select fuid,
       fbpid,
       fgamefsk
  from stage_dfqp.pb_gamecoins
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iju4a.png)
but when I change query like this(just add limit XXX) Exception disappear

```html
insert overwrite table stage_dfqp.user_currencypartition (dt='2018-05-16')
select fuid,
       fbpid,
       fgamefsk
  from stage_dfqp.pb_gamecoins limit 100
```

Hive table info:

```html
CREATE TABLE `stage_dfqp.user_currency`(
  `fuid` bigint , 
  `coin_type` string , 
  `coin_num` bigint
)
PARTITIONED BY ( 
  `dt` string)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.serde.ParquetHiveSerDe' 
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetInputFormat' 
OUTPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetOutputFormat'
```

Comment: Whats the exception ?

Comment: Error: java.io.IOException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException.....Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException。[Exception detail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iju4a.png)